# Group by, Case When and Cross Apply

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have this query below and it work fine but the issue is that its returning all records, what I want is to group by the specific [Type] under case when syntax and aggregate(sum) the activity so it only returns the sum of all transactions for the specific case when. I tried to test another query for Group by but then I cant seem to make the cross apply work. Can you please tell me what I might be doing wrong? or how I can integrate the group by into the cross apply query?

**Cross Apply**

```
    select v.type, left(M.Account, 4) as Entity, m.activity
from Test t cross apply
     (values (case when right(m.account, 9) = '1110.0130' then 'A'
                   when right(m.account, 9) = '1110.0131' then 'B'
                   when right(m.account, 9) = '1110.0132' then 'C'
                   when right(m.account, 9) between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' then 'D' 
              end)
     ) v(type)
where T.Accounting_Date between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-28' and
     (Left(M.Account,4) IN (@Entity) OR '' IN (@Entity)) and 
      v.type is not null;
```

**Group By**

```
Select 

Left(A.Account,4) Entity,Right(A.Account,9) As Base_Account, round(sum(A.Activity),2) As Total, Type

From (

        Select Account, debit+credit AS Activity, Accounting_Date,
            Case When right(account,9) = '1110.0130' then 'A' 
                 When right(account,9) = '1110.0131' then 'B'
                 When Substring(account,6,3) >'000' and Substring(account,6,3) < '200' and right(account,9) between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' then 'D'
            End AS [Type] From GLT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION 
        Where left(Account,4) = 'XYZ' and Accounting_Date >= '02/01/19' and Accounting_Date <= '02/28/19' AND substring(account,13,4)<'2000') A 

Group By Account, Type

Order by Base_Account
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to remove the `account` from the `group by`.

```
select v.type, sum(m.activity)
from Test t cross apply
     (values (case when right(m.account, 9) = '1110.0130' then 'A'
                   when right(m.account, 9) = '1110.0131' then 'B'
                   when right(m.account, 9) = '1110.0132' then 'C'
                   when right(m.account, 9) between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' then 'D' 
              end)
     ) v(type)
where T.Accounting_Date between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-28' and
     (Left(M.Account,4) IN (@Entity) OR '' IN (@Entity)) and 
      v.type is not null
group by type
```

Comment: why is it if i add more columns to the select statement than i get the error 'is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause' From what i understand or read i should be able to add more columns outside of the group by? or is there something specific in this query thats stopping me from doing it.

Comment: @Khan82 . . . In an aggregation query, all columns in the `select` that are not arguments to aggregation functions should be in the `group by`.